# How to test an SSL/TLS substrate is working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssl

I don't know how to frame this question, really.

I thinking of using  [SuperSocket](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/) for a an application. Its well written and seems fairly stable. Current version implements TLS between client/server for both async and sync connection using certificates and was wondering how to test the SSL/TLS layer is working. But how?

How would I test the layer is working? Does TLS encrypt the contents of the packet when transmitting? I've not done much in the way of ssl/tls dev, so any help appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a network analyzer (Wireshark or Unsniff) could help. But for TLS connection I recommend [ssldump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/).
Sample test command: ssldump -i eth0 port 9527 and host yourserveraddress

Please also refer to this link: [SSL/TLS connection monitoring/analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881333/ssl-tls-connection-monitoring-analysis)