# SSL/TLS connection monitoring/analysis

Tags: monitoring, analysis, ssl

I want to show the client that my client/server app is using a secure connection with mutual authentication.

My server app is implemented using C#, and the client is using C with OpenSSL. They can talk to each other and work fine. I'm trying do this demonstration with the two solutions below, but I'm not satisfied with the results.

1. Monitoring the connection using **[SSLDump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/)**:

   > The output is listed below, seems to be nothing wrong with it, but not sure about that. Please help me with this.
2. Monitoring the connection using **Wireshark**, and **[Unsniff](http://www.unleashnetworks.com/products/unsniff.html)**,

   > A network analysis tool, that can give me some kind of high level analysis result, could be very helpful with my demonstration. But when I watch the connection with these two tools, they all show me that the protocol is TCP, and I want they show me that protocol of the connection is SSL/TLS.

Any ideas?

> **Output from SSLDump**:
>   fan@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo ssldump -i eth0 port 9527 and host fan
>  
>   New TCP connection #1: 192.168.181.144(60992) <-> fan.local(9527)
>  
>   1 1  0.0044 (0.0044)  C>S  Handshake
>  
>         ClientHello
>  
>           Version 3.1 
>  
>           cipher suites
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc014
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc00a
>  
>           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>  
>           Unknown value 0x88
>  
>           Unknown value 0x87
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc00f
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc005
>  
>           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>  
>           Unknown value 0x84
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc012
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc008
>  
>           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc00d
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc003
>  
>           TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc013
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc009
>  
>           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>  
>           Unknown value 0x9a
>  
>           Unknown value 0x99
>  
>           Unknown value 0x45
>  
>           Unknown value 0x44
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc00e
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc004
>  
>           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>  
>           Unknown value 0x96
>  
>           Unknown value 0x41
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc011
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc007
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc00c
>  
>           Unknown value 0xc002
>  
>           TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
>  
>           TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>  
>           TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>  
>           TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
>  
>           TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
>  
>           Unknown value 0xff
>  
>           compression methods
>  
>                   unknown value
>  
>                     NULL
>  
>   1 2  0.2572 (0.2528)  S>C  Handshake
>  
>         ServerHello
>  
>           Version 3.1 
>  
>           session_id[32]=
>  
>             5e 08 00 00 82 35 0d a1 2a 91 c2 ac cb 62 1e f5 
>  
>             d0 88 3a d3 1a 64 58 a3 11 be 56 ef c4 fe 73 b7 
>  
>           cipherSuite         TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
>  
>           compressionMethod                   NULL
>  
>         Certificate
>  
>         CertificateRequest
>  
>           certificate_types                   rsa_sign
>  
>           certificate_types                   dss_sign
>  
>           certificate_authority
>  
>             30 4f 31 15 30 13 06 0a 09 92 26 89 93 f2 2c 64 
>  
>             01 19 16 05 6c 6f 63 61 6c 31 19 30 17 06 0a 09 
>  
>             92 26 89 93 f2 2c 64 01 19 16 09 4f 62 6a 65 63 
>  
>             74 69 76 61 31 1b 30 19 06 03 55 04 03 13 12 4f 
>  
>             62 6a 65 63 74 69 76 61 2d 42 4a 50 44 43 2d 43 
>  
>             41 
>  
>           certificate_authority
>  
>             30 6f 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 45 31 
>  
>             14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0a 13 0b 41 64 64 54 72 75 
>  
>             73 74 20 41 42 31 26 30 24 06 03 55 04 0b 13 1d 
>  
>             41 64 64 54 72 75 73 74 20 45 78 74 65 72 6e 61 
>  
>             6c 20 54 54 50 20 4e 65 74 77 6f 72 6b 31 22 30 
>  
>             20 06 03 55 04 03 13 19 41 64 64 54 72 75 73 74 
>  
>             20 45 78 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 20 43 41 20 52 6f 6f 
>  
>             74 
>  
>           certificate_authority
>  
>             30 81 c1 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55 53 
>  
>             31 17 30 15 06 03 55 04 0a 13 0e 56 65 72 69 53 
>  
>             69 67 6e 2c 20 49 6e 63 2e 31 3c 30 3a 06 03 55 
>  
>             04 0b 13 33 43 6c 61 73 73 20 31 20 50 75 62 6c 
>  
>             69 63 20 50 72 69 6d 61 72 79 20 43 65 72 74 69 
>  
>             66 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 41 75 74 68 6f 72 69 
>  
>             74 79 20 2d 20 47 32 31 3a 30 38 06 03 55 04 0b 
>  
>             13 31 28 63 29 20 31 39 39 38 20 56 65 72 69 53 
>  
>             69 67 6e 2c 20 49 6e 63 2e 20 2d 20 46 6f 72 20 
>  
>             61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 7a 65 64 20 75 73 65 20 6f 
>  
>             6e 6c 79 31 1f 30 1d 06 03 55 04 0b 13 16 56 65 
>  
>             72 69 53 69 67 6e 20 54 72 75 73 74 20 4e 65 74 
>  
>             77 6f 72 6b 
>  
>           certificate_authority
>  
>           ...
>  
>           certificate_authority
>  
>             30 52 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55 53 31 
>  
>             0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 08 13 02 43 41 31 12 30 10 
>  
>             06 03 55 04 07 13 09 50 61 6c 6f 20 41 6c 74 6f 
>  
>             31 10 30 0e 06 03 55 04 0a 13 07 42 6f 78 2e 6e 
>  
>             65 74 31 10 30 0e 06 03 55 04 03 13 07 62 6f 78 
>  
>             2e 6e 65 74 
>  
>           certificate_authority
>  
>             30 16 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 03 13 0b 58 59 5a 
>  
>             20 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 
>  
>         ServerHelloDone
>  
>   1 3  0.3889 (0.1316)  C>S  Handshake
>  
>         Certificate
>  
>   1 4  0.3889 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
>  
>         ClientKeyExchange
>  
>   1 5  0.3889 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
>  
>         CertificateVerify
>  
>           Signature[256]=
>  
>             02 fb a2 32 cd 1f 43 6e e7 1c b6 d8 8e a0 cc 49 
>  
>             6e 04 17 fa 8d 86 b0 a5 98 23 b0 19 ec f2 a5 8d 
>  
>             65 2d 31 81 73 96 43 89 19 81 ea 60 c8 12 4a 86 
>  
>             99 a5 b1 7b b5 29 ee 57 46 39 32 b4 f4 df 49 e0 
>  
>             97 35 c8 a2 e1 12 98 21 fa 75 87 9a 84 17 82 ba 
>  
>             72 a1 60 0a 44 3b 72 97 88 0c 44 0b 7c 14 f5 01 
>  
>             1b 47 90 fb c0 0e dc ae 91 c3 a4 38 c9 b7 c5 37 
>  
>             52 d6 4e a1 fb d5 87 35 df a3 cb 28 ab 73 f6 c3 
>  
>             b5 11 48 fc db 9b 84 a2 35 b7 c8 42 df b0 7a 20 
>  
>             b3 20 52 f0 6c 29 ae 96 4c 32 2e ba af ea 2e ad 
>  
>             2d ee 2e ed da 49 f7 55 38 29 7e 90 62 a7 03 4f 
>  
>             cd 76 14 36 b2 e0 a6 73 f2 7c c3 04 7f c1 a7 ca 
>  
>             db 5b 97 84 a7 df c3 e6 a5 15 0b f1 d6 bf e0 8b 
>  
>             7c 62 55 c9 2b 24 2d ac 8c 7b c8 72 70 9c ef 77 
>  
>             c4 5b d5 32 a8 30 6f e7 43 46 f9 47 05 c6 b9 4a 
>  
>             9d 98 6b f4 b6 bd 82 14 ec 65 99 42 f0 a0 9b 18 
>  
>   1 6  0.3889 (0.0000)  C>S  ChangeCipherSpec
>  
>   1 7  0.3889 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
>  
>   1 8  0.5480 (0.1591)  S>C  ChangeCipherSpec
>  
>   1 9  0.5480 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
>  
>   1 10 0.5502 (0.0022)  C>S  application_data
>  
>   1 11 0.5513 (0.0011)  C>S  application_data
>  
>   1 12 0.5517 (0.0004)  C>S  application_data
>  
>   1 13 0.5521 (0.0004)  C>S  application_data
>  
>   1 14 0.6444 (0.0923)  S>C  application_data
>  
>   1 15 9.8598 (9.2153)  C>S  application_data
>  
>   1 16 10.2293 (0.3694)  C>S  application_data
>  
>   1    12.3329 (2.1035)  C>S  TCP FIN
>  
>   1    12.3401 (0.0072)  S>C  TCP FIN

Comment: The fact that Wireshark shows you it's TCP doesn't mean anything, since SSL/TLS usually sits on top of TCP. In Wireshark, right-click on a TCP packet and choose 'Decode as...' (then SSL).

Comment: @Bruno Good to know that, it helps. Thanks! I'll try to decode the packet with my cert.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a normal SSL/TLS negotiation with a Client and Server certificate exchange. However at least the client and maybe the server look like they are running TLS 1.0. The use of TLS 1.2 and a more secure block cipher could be good depending on your security requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll make the demo with this sample output.

Comment: About server side app, I'm quite sure that it's using TLSv1.0 (RFC-2246). It has been well documented in MS dev doc.  

About client side app, I'm using TLSv1_client_method in OpenSSL, and according to the doc, I can not sure if it's using TLSv1.0, you can refer to this [link](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html#DESCRIPTION).  

About the block chiper, by saying the use of TLSv1.2 block cipher, you mean that I'm using TLSv1.2 block cipher for this TLSv1.0 connection (both server and client side), and I think I can change it by generate different certificates, right?

Comment: @fan you shouldn't need to change certificate (assuming you have a 2048-bit RSA certificate, for example): it's the cipher suite settings you'd want. (TLS 1.2 is still quite rare unfortunately. Try to use the highest version of TLS you can, with appropriate cipher suites.)